# array.length never equals zero and halts the program

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, string-matching

When no matches occur for a string, the length of that array does not equal `0` and it is impossible to craft a `if else` statement to allow for a `false` when there are no matches.

`value` is a multi-line input from a single `textarea`, `token` in this case is `var token = "//num"` defined in another function and passed in.

Here is my checking function:

```
function checkValid(value, token)
{
  // Checks to see if value contains the token
  var reg = new RegExp(token, "g");

  var result = value.match(reg);

  if (result.length == 1)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If the input text contains more than one instance of the token I get a false return, which is what I want, also a single occurrence of the token will return a true. But zero occurrences of the token will not allow any response. At this point I believe the program is halting but of course codepen gives no indication this is the case.

Comment: Debugging 101 `var result = value.match(reg); console.log(result);` Is it what you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When no matches occur, `match` returns `null` rather than an empty array.

Check that `result` exists before checking `result.length`.

```
function checkValid(value, token)
{
  // Checks to see if value contains the token
  var reg = new RegExp(token, "g");

  var result = value.match(reg);

  return result && result.length;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can check for this? I really need to return false if no occurrence is found.

Comment: @Joseph of course there is. You write code to check for that case.

Comment: Done! `if (result == null){ return false; }` EDIT: Ha the way you did it is very elegant!

Comment: It is not undefined, it returns null

Comment: @Joseph thinking about it more, I'd probably go with `return !!result`, since people seem to like to write things like `foo === false`

Answer (score 3):

`.match()` returns `null` if there is no match (see [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Description)), it doesn't return an empty array:

```
> 'aa'.match(new RegExp('a', 'g'))
[ 'a', 'a' ]
> 'a'.match(new RegExp('a', 'g'))
[ 'a' ]
> 'b'.match(new RegExp('a', 'g'))
null
```

You can then check if the result is null or not:

```
if (result === null) return false
```

or in a more compact way:

```
function checkValid(value, token)
{
  var reg = new RegExp(token, "g");
  var result = value.match(reg);
  return (result !== null && result.length === 1);
}
```